# How to remove all empty lines after a specific match

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

What I want to do is to remove all the empty lines after a specific match, and even the match itself.

**Original file:**

```
 line 1
 random words

 [GROUP 1]
 example 1
 example 2
 example 3

 [TITLE]


 [TITLE 2]
 line 2
 line 3

 [GROUP 2]

 random text...
```

**Result wanted:**

```
 line 1
 random words

 [GROUP 1]
 example 1
 example 2
 example 3

 [TITLE 2]
 line 2
 line 3

 random text...
```

Comment: I take it the match is `\[TITLE\]|\[GROUP 2\]`?

Comment: No it must work with any words into the brackets

Comment: But the other bracketed text is not removed, like `[TITLE 2]`.

Comment: You can use use something like ```\[(.*?)\]``` as match, can't you?

Comment: That regex also removes matches like `[TITLE 2]`, but `[TITLE 2]` is not deleted in the result wanted.

Comment: Ah sorry I get it wrong. Yes  ```[TITLE 2]``` should not be deleted, I was talking about working with any words into the brackets but of course only if the following line is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple ***sed*** solution:

```
sed -z 's/\[[^]]*\]\n\n\n*//g' file
```

- `-z` - treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII ‘NUL’ character) instead of a newline

---

Or a more sophisticated ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/\[.+\]/{ r=$0; rn=NR; c=0; next }rn && NR-rn==++c{ 
         if(NF) { if(NR-ern!=1) print r; rn=0 } else { ern=NR; next } 
    }1' file
```

The output:

```
line 1
random words

[GROUP 1]
example 1
example 2
example 3

[TITLE 2]
line 2
line 3

random text...
```